# Database date fields - Naming Convention

Tags: database-design, naming-conventions

What's a good way of naming date/datetime fields? Can't decide if I want to use things like `expiry_date`, `end_time`, `created_on`, or simply `expires`, `modified`.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379543/database-name-convention-datetime-column

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think either standard is okay but personally I find a column name like "modified" ambiguous without seeing the associated data type — is it boolean, a date, or a user ID?  I would prefer "modified_on", "modify_date", "is_modified", "modified_by" or something like that.

Answer (score 6):

I generally use "date_" as a prefix:

```
date_created
date_end
date_deleted
date_modified
```

As long as you're consistent, you should be in good shape. Alternatively, if you're working on an existing product, follow their standard. Changing conventions part of the way through is just annoying for the people behind you.

Comment: Most date fields I'm aware of are (rightly) much higher resolution than day.  Usually they are down to the second, and often have higher resolution than that.  As such, 'time_' might be a more accurate prefix, but the term date has a lot of history behind it and conveys meaning well.

Comment: True. Though I store datetimes by habit and filter to the resolution the app needs.

Comment: This is an old post, but I like to use `dt` as opposed to `date`

Answer (score 5):

I know this is pretty old, but I would like to throw out the suffix of "At".  So CreatedAt, or ModifiedAt.  Kinda makes sense in a convention approach, and doesn't require a type in the name.

Comment: I would argue that could be confused with a location, which goes back to the 'date' suffix/prefix suggestions.

Comment: @JasonH Not if you're consistent with the rule it shouldn't. Though, maybe "On" would be a better suffix as it eliminates this ambiguity from what I can see.

Comment: @Ryan I would agree that 'On' would be a better suffix than 'At'. Granted 'At' is typically used when specifying a time, whereas 'On' is specifying a date. Looking back on my original statement, I can see why some would prefer 'At'.